# How to retrieve data stored in a webserver DB using windows application in local machine

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

My local machine is using windows application for an appointment fixing. I want to retrieve data from webserver DB which also does appointment fixing by online for the same organisation. So I want both these to work in co-ordination. As my first step I want to import data.

Answer (score 0):

What problem are you having or concerned? Are you concerned about the concurrent use of the database and date entry, or are you concerned about possible duplication of work?

Also, why do you need a Windows application when you already have a web app? What platform is the Windows application written in (.NET, Win32)?